# How to access this website http://10.10.5.165/ without connection to a specific WiFi?

Tags: web, wifi

I'm trying to open http://10.10.5.165/ but it won't load unless I connect to a specific WiFi (office's wifi), is there any way to tackle it? Thanks

I've only tried to turn off my wifi and try all kinds of internet connection, but it seems like it'll only work if it's using that specific WiFi

Comment: `internet connection` - since 10.x.x.x are **private** addresses, *internet connection* is irrelevant

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the address because it's **reserved for use in a local network** - no one globally can control such an address.

#### There are multiple IP ranges defined as «reserved»:

- **10.0.0.0/8** - ranging from 10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.255 *(subnet mask 255.0.0.0)*
- **172.16.0.0/12** - ranging from 172.16.0.0 to 172.31.255.255 *(subnet mask 255.240.0.0)*
- **192.168.0.0/16** - ranging from 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.255.255 *(subnet mask 255.255.0.0)*
- **100.64.0.0/10** (Carrier Grade NAT) - ranging from 100.64.0.0 to 100.127.255.255 *(subnet mask 255.192.0.0)*
- **127.0.0.0/8** (localhost) - ranging from 127.0.0.0 to 127.255.255.255 *(subnet mask 255.0.0.0)*

The list isn't exhaustive, though. For more information, you can check out the [RFC6890 (Special-Purpose IP Address Registries)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6890.txt).

#### There is a way to reach to that address from the outside, though...

Specifically, you would have to set up a Virtual Private Network on your office Wi-Fi router (a VPN for short) - that way, you'll be able to access all local resources that your local network offers.

Answer (score 0):

how do yu configured your public ip "10.10.5.165" ? if you have configured in your wifi router, you can associate **DMZ** to your **local machine** and **wifi** and local machine must be always in **running**.

your problems is not explicit. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your 10.10.5.165 only exists in your local network environment. If you want to access it from anywhere, you can try using a [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network), such as [WireGuard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WireGuard).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The IP address "10.XX.XX.XX" falls within the range defined by RFC 1918 for private IP addresses. Private IP addresses are reserved for use within private networks and are not routable over the public internet. The specific range for private IP addresses in the 10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.255 range.

In practical terms, this means that if a website or service is using an IP address in the 10.XX.XX.XX range, it is intended for internal use within a specific network. Accessing it directly over the public internet is not possible unless the network is configured to allow external connections.